# Could not use lookup file module for a file under /etc/

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I am deploying a CentOS machine and one among the tasks was to read a file that is rendered the Consul service which places it under `/etc/sysconfig`. I am trying to later read it in a variable using the `lookup` module but it is throwing an error below:

> fatal: [ansible_vm1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "could not locate file in lookup: /etc/sysconfig/idb_EndPoint"}

But I am running the lookup task way below the point where the `idb_EndPoint` file is generated and also I looked it up manually logging in to verify the file was available.

```
 - name: importing the file contents to variable
   set_fact:
     idb_endpoint: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/sysconfig/idb_EndPoint') }}"
   become: true
```

I also tried previlege escalations with another user `become_user: deployuser` along with `become: true` but didn't work still. Using the Ansible version 2.2.1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All lookup plugins in Ansible are executed locally on the control machine.

Instead use [`slurp` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/slurp_module.html):

```
- name: importing the file contents to variable
  slurp:
    src: /etc/sysconfig/idb_EndPoint
  register: idb_endpoint_b64
  become: true

- set_fact:
    idb_endpoint: "{{ idb_endpoint_b64.content | b64decode }}"
```

Comment: Great! testing it now. Found it myself to use the `b64decode` construct

Comment: I also added a `replace('\n', '')` after `b64decode` to remove the trailing new lines

Comment: "Lines"? Were there multiple ones?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I tested copying a file to the target, slurping it back and compared bit-by-bit with the source - they are the same, no newline is added.

Comment: Never mind, I think it was present in the file I was slurping it, a single line and followed by a new line. Never mind, it worked